# Resultset handling error in servlet code

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I write a code in servlet for login checking I don't know why I get an error like `java.sql.SQLException: No data found`, if I had not commented out the `String s4 = rs.getString(1)` and `out.println(s4)` line if I commented out this lines I did not get any error.

Why do I get an error like this? I cannot find out the answer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class login extends HttpServlet {

    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    String s = "";

    public void init() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:edsn");
            s = "Your information is connected ......";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            s = "Exception 1....." + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println(s);
        try {

            String ID = req.getParameter("T1");
            String query = "select * from user_db ";
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            out.println("user" + " " + "pass");
            while (rs.next()) {

                try {
                    if ((rs.getString(1)).equals(ID)) {
                        String s4 = rs.getString(1);
                        out.println(s4);

                        out.println("<html><body><h> login Pass.....:(</h></body></html>");

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println(e);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Unable To Show the info... . . ." + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would reduce the amount of code you're posting to contain only the relevant sections, and rephrase your question to be clear in what works vs. what doesn't

Comment: http://simpledevelopment.weebly.com/2/post/2008/12/javasqlsqlexception-no-data-found.html

Comment: I can solve this problem by storing the value in a variable and use it,but my question is another why it is not working.I thik that Resultset value will be null after one use,use may be storing value or showing value.Am I correct?

Comment: @fgb I read this article it is really helpful for me but I have a question Resultset is a application feature is it dependents on database driver?I am new in java.I think driver is just like a bridge to make a connection, after completing connection all action will be control is hand over to application how to manage buffer or other.I have another question is that if database server in another location and application in another location when resultset is made then where it stored in application or database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why write the code like this ? It's very wasteful going over the whole table... 
The IO alone...
Why not change to this:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement st = null;
try {...
String ID = req.getParameter("T1"); 
            String query = "select 1 from user_db where col_name = ?"; 
            st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            st.setString(1, ID);  
            rs = st.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
  out.println(ID); 
  out.println("<html><body><h> login Pass.....:(</h></body></html>"); 
}
..

} finally {
if (rs != null) try { rs.close();}catch (Exception e) {}
if (st != null) try { st.close();}catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

notice prepared statements are cached and better for frequent use

you let the db do what its good at - search the data

select 1 instead of select * does not bring back data you dont really need

jdbc works harder the more columns and data in general you return, so only get what you 
need

and add a finally block to always close your db connections properly

Answer (score 0):

Calling methods on Connection, Statement, or ResultSet depend on which JDBC driver you've loaded. All the values of the ResultSet could be set as soon as the query is made, or they could be retrieved from the database as they're needed, depending on the implementation of the driver.

The JdbcOdbcDriver throws an SQLException after calling getString for a second time. This can be worked around be storing the values in Strings instead of making multiple calls, or by switching to a different driver.